# Is there a 'correct' way to convert an image to grayscale in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

In Photoshop, there are several ways to convert an image into black & white. For example:

1. `Image > Adjustments > Desaturate`;
2. `Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation` and set the Saturation to `0`;
3. Adding a completely black layer on top with the `Saturation` blend mode.

For 1. and 2. the outcome is identical, but 3. yields something different. Which method is the 'right' one to use, if there is any?

Comment: `Image > Adjustments > Black & White`

Comment: hi user25914, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I edited your question to make it more legible. If you feel this no longer reflects your problem, feel free to re-edit. Thanks again and enjoy the site!

Comment: The 'right' method is the one that gives you an outcome you're happy with.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there are even more ways to make an image gray scale, e.g. via the channel mixer or several other methods, explained in this post:

**[How do I change a single layer to grayscale in Photoshop CS4?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-do-i-change-a-single-layer-to-grayscale-in-photoshop-cs4/3757#3757)**

Some of them offer different opportunities of fine tuning, yielding in very different outcomes. So there isn't really a 'right' method.

See those articles for some interesting results:

[**Digital photography school: seven ways to create sepia images**](http://digital-photography-school.com/discover-seven-ways-to-create-sepia-images-in-photoshop/)

[**Spoongraphics: the best way to make your photos black and white**](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/the-best-ways-to-make-your-photos-black-white)

Answer (score 1):

The "black and white" adjustment layer offers the most fine tuning options.

**[Photoshop tips for the best way to convert to grayscale](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2013/11/26/photoshop-black-and-white-conversion-tips-the-best-ways-to-make-mono-images/)**

If you're shooting in RAW, the h/s/l adjustments are the second best option.

Other ways of executing are fine; they just offer less control over the details.

Answer (score 1):

I had a teacher in college tell us the best way to convert a file to grayscale was to first convert the RGB document to LAB, then delete the A/B Channels. It provides a pretty could starting point, though I've yet to use it very often in my workflow 12 years after the fact…

I think there are a bunch of different ways to do this, and you may or may not see different results with any of them, but it might be good to try a couple and see which one gives you the bed result for the image you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

if you really really convert an image to grayscale, the **best way** is:
**Edit > Convert profile > Output profile > Gray Gramma  2.2**
If you click in Channel panel, you look one channel (Gray), but with the other method you still look 3(RGB/LAB) o 4(CMYK) channels.

Good Luck.